# filtering a column that has str and float numbers

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Assume we have a dataframe and we are interested in 1 column in order to create a new one. So let's deal with that column only. That column has the following format

```
df
A
n.a
0.74
0.3
1
n.a
...
```

I want to create a new column that:

- whenever the value in the column A is n.a. OR smaller than 1 then set my new column equal to a variable that I have (which is str)
- If the value is 1 then it should fill n.a.
  So in our previous example the dataframe should look something like this

```
A         New col
n.a       15/2/2022
0.74      15/2/2022
0.3       15/2/2022
1         n.a.
n.a       15/2/2022
...
```

I tried the following

```
   df['New col'] = 'n.a.'
   if df['A']!='n.a.':
       if df['A']< 1:
           df['New col']=date
```

I am sure this is not the optimal or even a good way to do it. However, I get the following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

which I do not understand why

Comment: What i your `date` variable?

Comment: Also, don't use the string `n.a.`, use `float.NaN` or `None`, because when using string, it changes the `dtype` of your column from `float` to `object`

Comment: hey thank you for your feedback. I have updated the question. The dataframe is created by reading it from an excel file and it needs to be n.a.

Comment: Why not handle all input values as string ?

Answer (score 1):

If need set to `n.a.` only if greater or `equal` 1 use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and `errors='coerce'`:

```
date = '15/2/2022'
df['new'] = np.where(pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce') >= 1, 'n.a.', date)

print (df)
      A        new
0   n.a  15/2/2022
1  0.74  15/2/2022
2   0.3  15/2/2022
3     1       n.a.
4   n.a  15/2/2022
```